# Is there a convenient way to read non-utf8 encoding file into incanter?

Tags: clojure, incanter

It seems Incanter can only recognize utf-8 encoding file while native clojure  `slurp` can read non-utf8 encoding file with `:encoding` keyword, So is it possible to combine those two functions together ,but I don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first parameter could be filename, URL, or anything that could be handled by `clojure.io/reader`, so you can write something like:

```
(read-dataset (InputStreamReader. (FileInputStream. "data/co2.csv") "ISO-8859-1"))
```